# Video sharing via intent to Apps like Viber and Line throws to error

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to share a video file in my App via this code:

```
     Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(path);
     share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
     share.setType("video/*");
     context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share video using"));
```

it works and sharing window opens, but it some Apps like Viber and Line i get error! Viber says "The selected file is unsupported or appears to be corrupted". But for example WhatsApp can share video successfully.

it does not related to the video format because the same video can be share from Gallery App to all of others Apps like Viber, Line and...

How i can fix this? there is something other to add to my intent that Apps like Viber can detect it as a valuable information to parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I made it work by adding the following prefix to the video String path: 'content://media'
So your code should look something like:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile("content://media" + path);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setType("video/*");
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share video using"));
```

I hope that can help you out because it did the trick for me.